# JBOSS throwing Exception when trying to Restfull Webservices using JAXRS

Tags: rest, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have developed a sample RestEasy Hello World Example for my self assessment, but when i try to run this project using JBOSS7.0 i see a printed stack trace of error mentioned below:Please suggest me with possible solution or let me know if i have coded wrongly in the above mentioned xml and java files.

```
 12:54:44,145 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/resteasy]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at org.scannotation.WarUrlFinder.findWebInfClassesPath(WarUrlFinder.java:56) [scannotation-1.0.3.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ListenerBootstrap.getScanningUrls(ListenerBootstrap.java:64) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap.createDeployment(ConfigurationBootstrap.java:147) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ListenerBootstrap.createDeployment(ListenerBootstrap.java:32) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:27) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext from [Module "org.scannotation.scannotation:main" from local module loader @a9c09e (roots: D:\jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)

12:54:44,175 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-6) Context [/resteasy] startup failed due to previous errors
12:54:44,183 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/resteasy]] (MSC service thread 1-6) Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextDestroyed(ResteasyBootstrap.java:37) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.2.1.GA.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3465) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3970) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3888) [jbossweb-7.0.0.CR4.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.0.Final.jar:7.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18]
```

Following is the program i have written

Maven -> pom.xml
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0
      com.javacodegeeks
      resteasy
      0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      war
      resteasy JEE5 Webapp
      http://maven.apache.org

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>org.jboss.resteasy</id>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>resteasy</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

MessageDriven.java

```
package com.sandeep.resteasy;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/message")
public class MessageDriven {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

        String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the auto-scanning context parameter.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

JBoss AS7 does its own auto-scanning and adding the `resteasy.scan` context parameter will cause this error when running under AS7.

Comment: I had the problem with WildFly 10.2.